# Can't pinpoint error near the LIKE keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I'm running into an error with a sql inquery near my LIKE statement. Am I formatting the LIKE clause incorrectly within the WHEN clause of a CASE? Here is the code.

```
SELECT
substring (Cases.FileNumber,4,6) AS [FileNumber]
,Charge.ChargeCode
,Cases.BookedLastName
,Cases.BookedFirstName
,Cases.ArrestDate
,Cases.BookedDOB
,Cases.BookedAge
,Charge.OffenseToDate
,Cases.BookedRace
,Cases.BookedSex
,Charge.OffenseStreetAddress1
,Charge.OffenseCity
,Charge.OffenseState
,Charge.OffenseZipCode
,Charge.ChargeDescription
,(SELECT CASE
WHEN charge1.ChargeDescription LIKE N'%heroin%' THEN 'Heroin'
      ELSE 'Not Heroin'
      END
  FROM tblCsCharge AS charge1
           INNER JOIN tblCsCases AS cases1
                           ON charge1.FileNumber = cases1.FileNumber
 WHERE
      charge1.BookedLastName = cases1.BookedLastName
      AND charge1.BookedLastName = cases1.BookedLastName
      AND charge1.BookedDOB = Cases.BookedDOB
      AND cases2.ChargeCode IN (N'579.015-001Y201735')) AS HeroinYN
FROM
    tblCsCases AS Cases
    INNER JOIN tblCsCharge AS Charge
        ON Cases.FileNumber = Charge.FileNumber
    WHERE Cases.IssuedDate >= 01/01/2017
    AND
    Cases.IssuedDate <= @EndDate
    AND
    Charge.ChargeCode IN (N'579.015-001Y201735')
    AND
    Cases.BookedLastName NOT IN (N'Bogus')

    ORDER By
    Cases.BookedLastName
```

This is a sub-query within a bigger query focused on building a column that will simply output Heroin or Not Heroin based off of a large text field in our database.

EDITs:

Despite the changes that should make the code compile, the following error now occurs:
Invalid column name 'BookedLastName'.
Invalid column name 'BookedLastName'.
Invalid column name 'BookedDOB'.
The multi-part identifier "cases2.ChargeCode" could not be bound.

Comment: It seems you are missing a close paren before `AS HeroinYN` and mixing the searched form of CASE.

Comment: "not liking the code", and what **exactly** do you mean by that?

Comment: You can't combine the two variations of `CASE`, either you do `CASE expression WHEN value THEN ...` or you do `CASE WHEN expression THEN`, you're combining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code, both of which were pointed out, though not in the same answer.

1. Your case statement should be without the column name in parenthesis - I commented it out in the copy of your code below)
2. You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the query, right before the alias - I added it below.

.

```
,(SELECT CASE--(charge1.ChargeDescription)
      WHEN charge1.ChargeDescription LIKE N'%heroin%' THEN 'Heroin'
      ELSE 'Not Heroin'
      END
  FROM tblCsCharge AS charge1
           INNER JOIN tblCsCases AS cases1
                           ON charge1.FileNumber = cases1.FileNumber
 WHERE
      charge1.BookedLastName = cases1.BookedLastName
      AND charge1.BookedLastName = cases1.BookedLastName
      AND charge1.BookedDOB = Cases.BookedDOB
      AND cases2.ChargeCode IN (N'579.015-001Y201735')) AS HeroinYN
```

Comment: Removing the column name from after CASE yields an error stating that BookedLastName, BookeDOB, and ChargeCode are invalid column names. I've triple checked that those are, in fact, the right column names including capitalization. They function in another sub-query in a different file that doesn't use CASE. 

I believe our database is SQL Server. does the CASE query only work with T-SQL or should it be working with SQL server too?

Comment: This query will parse correctly - The issue may be in the greater query which you haven't posted (this seems to be just a part of it)

Comment: TSQL is SQL Server's implementation of the SQL language @JackOfTales. Post your entire query since Eli and my answer both would avoid the error based of what you have posted (though ELI needs to add the parentheses to his answer lol.

Comment: @scsimon thought I added it there... thanks for the touchup.

Comment: It was just a part, the part I thought was incorrect. The rest of the query has worked fine for me before without issue. I've provided the full thing above however.

Comment: This would still compile (with the declaration of the @enddate variable); what error message are you getting? Please post that as well

Comment: @Eli, I've edited the above message to include it. The error received states: Invalid column name 'BookedLastName'.
Invalid column name 'BookedLastName'.
Invalid column name 'BookedDOB'.
The multi-part identifier "cases2.ChargeCode" could not be bound.

Comment: ok... your last line in the nested query (has the alias `cases2` when it should be `cases1` (you don't have a `cases2`). Try fixing that, and see if the other errors still come up -

Comment: @Eli, They still do. I'm using Report builder 3.0 for lack of any other way to get to the server. I've ensured I am connected to the database. The error only shows up with this specific query and no other queries.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the issue..

`AND cases2.ChargeCode IN (N'579.015-001Y201735') AS HeroinYN`

Since this is part of a sub-query, you need another parenthese

`AND cases2.ChargeCode IN (N'579.015-001Y201735')) AS HeroinYN`

**ALSO**

You can't put the column name after a `CASE` statement when you are using an equality operator.

This is acceptable

```
select
   case columnName
      when 'X' then 1
      when 'Y' then 0
   end
```

This is not

```
select
   case columnName
      when = 'X' then 1
      when columnName like '%Y%' then 0
   end
```

**CORRECTED SCRIPT**

```
,(SELECT CASE
      WHEN charge1.ChargeDescription LIKE N'%heroin%' THEN 'Heroin'
      ELSE 'Not Heroin'
      END
  FROM tblCsCharge AS charge1
           INNER JOIN tblCsCases AS cases1
                           ON charge1.FileNumber = cases1.FileNumber
 WHERE
      charge1.BookedLastName = cases1.BookedLastName
      AND charge1.BookedLastName = cases1.BookedLastName
      AND charge1.BookedDOB = Cases.BookedDOB
      AND cases2.ChargeCode IN (N'579.015-001Y201735')) AS HeroinYN
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for that is:

```
CASE 
    WHEN charge1.ChargeDescription LIKE N'%heroin%' THEN 'Heroin'
    ELSE 'Not Heroin'
END
```

Don't put the field name after `CASE` in this syntax.